# types of facebook application and their differences

Tags: facebook

I try to understand the difference betweeen a facebook canvaas application and a facebook enabled website. For me the only difference is that Canvas integrates into Facebook with an iFrame and Websites are stand allone.

But in terms of policy and functionality these two types look the same. Is this true or am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all extents and purposes they are the same.  On Canvas/Page apps there is an additional signed_request post that is sent to your application with a little FB specific information that doesn't get provided to the website.

Comment: thanks Dustin. I did additional research, reading all the terms and platform policies. I came to the same conclusion, see my post below.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the Platform Policies and there was an interesting definition:
By "Application" we mean canvas page application, Platform integration, or any other technical integration we have assigned an application identification number

I assume in terms of policy they are all treated the same way. One exeption: Games on canvas pages are obligated to use Facebook Credits.

In terms of functionality it seems that canvas pages have the advantage of sending requests and using bookmarks. Now for games there are additonal stories during playing.